# jQuery .on event handler inconsistently triggered from anchor element 'click'

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I recently developed a site, http://www.bandwidthpool.com, a bandwidth bidding site.  I use dynamic page loading for a smoother experience, but have recently noticed some issues.  Navigation links and buttons are all  elements.  A number of times I notice you will have to click on the link/button twice sometimes more to get it to trigger the click event.  There doesn't appear to be a rhyme or reason, I haven't been able to figure out any pattern or reasoning behind this behavior.

I set up a test page to better illustrate this:

http://www.bandwidthpool.com/_test/

Clicking around on the buttons you will notice sometimes you have to click it a few times to fire the event.  The code is pretty straightforward...

### _Test.js button event handler

```
$(document)
.on('click', sel.testButton, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(sel.testDisplay)
        .html($(this).html())
        .css('color', $(this).data('color'));
});
```

The buttons are simply anchor elements in a list:

It seems to show this behavior on all the browsers.  As far as I know, the '.on' method is the most recent and reliable way of attaching event handlers ... is this known to be buggy? I am using jQuery 1.7.1.  Thanks for any help, and let me know if you need any more information.

### Full _Test.js code

```
BWPool._Test = 
{
    handlers : [],                  // Container for event handlers       
    selectors : {
        testDisplay :  'div.test-display',
        testButton :   'div.test-buttons li a',
    },
    init : function() {
        var self = this; var sel = this.selectors        
        self.initHandlers();        
    },
    initHandlers : function() {
        var self = this; var sel = this.selectors        
        $(document)
        .on('click', sel.testButton, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(sel.testDisplay)
                .html($(this).html())
                .css('color', $(this).data('color'));
        });
    },

    // Remove event handlers and timers
    destruct : function() {
        var self = this; var sel = self.selectors;         
        $.each(self.handlers, function(i, handler) {
            $(document).off(handler.event, handler.selector);    
        });        

    }      
};
$(function() {    BWPool._Test.init();    })
```

Comment: What is sel.testButton? a string? a dom element?

Comment: Yes a string representing the dom element, the rest of the file is just kind of skeleton code that I use in all of the JS files for that site, but I included the full file.

Comment: And I tested your `_test` page and all the buttons worked with every click ... using FF19. The problem seems to be related to Chrome, especially if you click on the non-text part of the button

Comment: I can replicate it on FF, but it doesn't happen as often and I never have to click more than twice on a button to trigger it, but it still happens.  It's really annoying how it happens so sporadically, makes it very difficult to debug.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If anyone has any suggestions or insight that would be greatly appreciated.  Should I go back to using 'live' instead of 'on'? Has anyone else experienced this issue? It's odd because it only happens with the buttons and not direct text links (even though they are both <a> elements)